# Prisma queryRaw returning date as string

Tags: sql, typescript, date, prisma

**Issue**: When I use prisma.$queryRaw, it returns my date as a string, even though I specify the query's return type.  If I use prisma.find then it returns it correctly.  But, I have to use queryRaw because of the complexity of the query.

schema.prisma has the date defined like such:

`effectiveDate  DateTime? @map("effective_date") @db.Date`

So, the model object has the field defined like `effectiveDate: Date | null`

The query looks something like this:

```
const catalogCourses: CatalogCourse[] = await prisma.$queryRaw<CatalogCourse[]>`
    SELECT
      id,
      campus,
      effective_date as "effectiveDate",

...rest of the query ommitted here because it's not important
```

If I then do something like

```
console.log(`typeof date: ${typeof catalogCourses[0].effectiveDate}, value ${catalogCourses[0].effectiveDate}`)
```

The result shows `typeof date: string, value 2000-12-31`.  Why isn't it a date?  I need to be able to work with it as a Date, but if I do effectiveDate.getTime() for example, it errors during runtime, saying 'getTime is not a function', which it is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).   <strike>If I try and do new Date(effectiveDate), that doesn't work either because typescript sees the field as a Date object already.</strike> EDIT: I was incorrect about why the previous statement wasn't working; doing new Date(effectiveDate) *does* work.

I do see in the prisma docs that it says:

> Type caveats when using raw SQL When you type the results of
> $queryRaw, the raw data does not always match the suggested TypeScript
> type.

Is there a way for queryRaw to return my date as a Date object?

Comment: `because typescript sees the field as a Date object already` - but you defined that by yourself in your `CatalogCourse` type. Just redefine it as string there and then call `new Date(effectiveDate)`. If `CatalogCourse` type is from prisma then you cannot use this type there, you are tricking TS with typecasting to think that return type is Date, but in reality it is a string, you should not do that. Define your own type.

Comment: It's a date in the database, and it's a date in the model object.  The field correctly gets populated as a date when I do prisma.findMany (or something other than raw sql).  Changing the model object to be a string is not the fix.

Comment: I think you don't really understand how it works. `It's a date in the database` does not mean anything because it's DB date, not JS date. `Prisma.findMany` of course does conversion under the hood. But `queryRaw` does not know anything about field types and just fetches `raw` fields from DB, and raw date field from DB is a string. Currently you just bypassing this error by tricking TS to think that `queryRaw` returns a date.

Comment: You're right, I am asking the question because I don't know how Prisma works.  It sounds like you're saying that the part in their documentation that says "the raw data does not always match the suggested TypeScript type." is true for dates, and there's nothing really to be done about it

Comment: It would be nice if prisma would create types for the JSON serialised forms of model objects because having to define these manually is a recipe for errors!